# How to change value of string from onSucces class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Here i read some input which i want to use for creating "Produs" object which i upload it to the firebase storage, then i want to retrieve it to display a list of objects, i have a problem when i want to update the path to the image storage, to retrieve it later.

```
public class Add extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    EditText etNume, etCantitate, etPret;
    Button btnSubmit, btnImage;
    Uri mImage;
    ImageView ivTest;
    public static String path="";
    StorageReference mStorageRef;
    final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        etNume = findViewById(R.id.etNume);
        etCantitate = findViewById(R.id.etCantitate);
        etPret = findViewById(R.id.etPret);
        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnImage = findViewById(R.id.btnImage);
        ivTest =findViewById(R.id.ivTest);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        btnImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });



        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nume, pret,cantitate;
                nume = etNume.getText().toString().trim();
                pret = etPret.getText().toString().trim();
                cantitate = etCantitate.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nume)){
                    etNume.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pret)){
                    etPret.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(cantitate)){
                    etCantitate.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                StorageReference file = mStorageRef.child("Produs").child(nume + ".jpg");
                file.putFile(mImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        path += taskSnapshot.getMetadata().toString(); /// good path
                        Toast.makeText(Add.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(Add.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();/// null path
                Produs p=new Produs(nume,cantitate,pret,path);
                Task task =mDatabase.child("Produs").child(nume).setValue(p);


                task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                        Toast.makeText(Add.this, "Produsul a fost adaugat cu succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    }
                });

                task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Add.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            mImage = data.getData();
            ivTest.setImageURI(mImage);


        }
    }

}
```

How to have path changed from the onSuccess method?
Basically i want to change the path after i upload an image to build " Produs " object
Also, this is the good path to the image storage? As taskSnapshot.getdownloadURL() doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not where you set and read the `path` variable, the problem is **when** you do this. Since the `getDownloadURL()` method makes a call to the server, its `onSuccess` may run much later than you think.

If you're seeing the wrong value for `path`, it's very likely that the `onSuccess` that sets it hasn't run yet. The easiest way to verify that is by either setting breakpoints on the read and write and running in a debugger, or by adding some logging and checking the order of that in your logcat.

The solution for this type of problem is always the same: any code that needs the download URL, needs to either be inside `onSuccess`, be called from there, or be synchronized in some other way.

So in your case, move the `` into the `onSuccess`:

```
StorageReference file = mStorageRef.child("Produs").child(nume + ".jpg");
file.putFile(mImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        path += taskSnapshot.getMetadata().toString(); /// good path
        Toast.makeText(Add.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Toast.makeText(Add.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Produs p=new Produs(nume,cantitate,pret,path);
        Task task =mDatabase.child("Produs").child(nume).setValue(p);

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
            ...
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

For more on this, see:

- [How to store download image url in realtime database firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967042/how-to-store-download-image-url-in-realtime-database-firebase-android/68967398#68967398)
- [How to store Url into ArrayList from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179709/how-to-store-url-into-arraylist-from-firebase-storage/68180018#68180018)
- [Can someone help me with logic of the firebase on success listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039870/can-someone-help-me-with-logic-of-the-firebase-on-success-listener/57040546#57040546)
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Not all of these are directly about Cloud Storage for Firebase, but the explanation applies here as well.